# Monkey patching Ruby's Hash class

Tags: ruby

What could be the repercussions of monkey patching Hash to act like this:

```
class Hash
  def method_missing(method,*args, &block)
    if self.has_key?(method)
      return self[method]
    elsif self.has_key?(method.to_s)
      return self[method.to_s]
    else
      return nil
    end
  end
end
```

My justification is the following:

Basically, when I add objects to hashes, I make sure their keys.to_s are unique.

Should I be concerned, Am I missing something?

```
h = { :foo => "bar", "hello" => "bar" }

h.foo => "bar"
h.hello => "bar"
```

Comment: Why don't you use `HashWithIndifferentAccess`?

Comment: Besides that I didn't know about the class :-), ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess::HashWithIndifferentAccess requires rails. Also, it does not allow "dot getters" (h.foo which is faster to type than h["foo"] and h[:foo])

Comment: "Faster to type" is a very bad reason to implement this ...

Comment: It is dirty to allow symbols and strings to be saved as keys and let them mean the same thing. Instead, you should convert all keys to either symbols or strings when you save to the hash. That will simplify your code when calling the values.

Comment: @DamienMATHIEU unless there are no (serious) repercussions, which is the reason I'm asking this question.

Comment: Well, monkey patching will make your code impossible to read in the long term. Not to speak the learning curve for new developers. See http://devblog.avdi.org/2008/02/23/why-monkeypatching-is-destroying-ruby/

Comment: If you come from a JavaScript background, this might be the way you prefer to interface with data objects. Within Ruby it's generally frowned upon, as it confuses "dumb" data objects, where the keys are arbitrary, and proper classes, where the method calls must be specific.

Answer (score 7):

There is a native ruby object for this: [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html).

You can instantiate an `OpenStruct` with a hash.

```
o = OpenStruct.new(hello: 'world')
```

Once it is initialized, you can use all the keys as methods.

```
o.hello #=> "world"
```

Therefore you don't need to monkey-patch your hash (which can lead to weird behaviors indeed).

And OpenStruct manages internally the duplicates between string and symbol entries.

```
OpenStruct.new(:hello => 'world', 'hello' => 'world2') #=> #<OpenStruct hello="world2">
```

Comment: downside: you lose important methods (like `Hash#count`, `Hash#keys`, `Hash#values`, ... including most of `Enumerable`'s methods)

Comment: Interesting class! It doesn't allow me to use existing Hash objects nor those coming from other gems though. tessi's comment is alerting too. @tessi, thanks for bringing this up :-)

Comment: `hash = {hello: 'world'}; o = OpenStruct.new(hash)` <- You can indeed use existing hashes.

Comment: @tessi Virtually every method has been stripped out to reduce this to a blank state so there's no collisions with your own attributes. Arguably this is a feature, but it's good to remind people those facilities are not available.

Answer (score 1):

BAD IDEA!!

If you misspell any of the valid methods of hash, you will get a nil instead of the real method missing. Eg: {}.count => 0, {}.counts => nil instead of NoMethodError: undefined method `counts' for {}:Hash.

Comment: This isn't an argument against using this technique. You'd have *exactly* the same problems if using a Hash in the first place. This method is for convenience, not method safety.